# Does と mark reported speech here?

Tags: grammar

どうしようか**と**相談しているところに知らせが届いた。
While discussing *what to do*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is a bit convoluted but yes the と reports that the speaker (?) was asking about what to do when the message (?) arrived.